# Python Tifffile: Problems with loading images in SageMaker

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am using Tifffile to load .tiff-image files and then to convert them to a PIL image to process them. I use this workaround because other methods had problems with some specific TIFF-images. On my local machine, the following code is running fine. But when I run the code in the SageMaker environment, it does not work

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import os
import random
import tifffile
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import matplotlib
#import imagecodecs
# Causes errors with some pictures
#image = np.expand_dims(scipy.ndimage.imread(image_path), 0)
    
# Causes errors with some pictures
#image = np.expand_dims(matplotlib.pyplot.imread(image_path), 0)
    
# This works on my local machine, but not in Amazon SageMaker
# Use tifffile to load the image
img = tifffile.imread(image_path)
# Make into "PIL Image" and carry on as usual
image = Image.fromarray(img)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-fe721f47a3dc> in <module>
----> 1 batch_image_augmentation(test_images, 20)

<ipython-input-134-b0ca28d40a9c> in batch_image_augmentation(path_list, n)
      3         target_dir = "./Test/" + path[:-5] + "_AUG"
      4         print(path)
----> 5         augment_image(path, target_dir, n)

<ipython-input-131-cdef2a00cd5f> in augment_image(image_path, target_dir, n)
     24     #Some images cause problems, so I try the same workaround as in the PNG-conversion script
     25     # Use tifffile to load the image
---> 26     img = tifffile.imread(image_path)
     27     # Make into "PIL Image" and carry on as usual
     28     image = Image.fromarray(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in imread(files, **kwargs)
    719         if isinstance(files, (str, os.PathLike)) or hasattr(files, 'seek'):
    720             with TiffFile(files, **kwargs_file) as tif:
--> 721                 return tif.asarray(**kwargs)
    722 
    723     with TiffSequence(files, **kwargs_seq) as imseq:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, key, series, level, out, maxworkers)
   2805                     typecode, product(series.shape), out=out)
   2806         elif len(pages) == 1:
-> 2807             result = pages[0].asarray(out=out, maxworkers=maxworkers)
   2808         else:
   2809             result = stack_pages(pages, out=out, maxworkers=maxworkers)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, out, squeeze, lock, reopen, maxworkers)
   5646 
   5647             for _ in self.segments(
-> 5648                 func=func, lock=lock, maxworkers=maxworkers, sort=True
   5649             ):
   5650                 pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in segments(self, lock, maxworkers, func, sort)
   5510                 *self._offsetscounts, lock=lock, sort=sort, flat=True
   5511             ):
-> 5512                 yield decode(segment)
   5513         else:
   5514             # reduce memory overhead by processing chunks of up to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in decode(args, decodeargs, keyframe, func)
   5499 
   5500         def decode(args, decodeargs=decodeargs, keyframe=keyframe, func=func):
-> 5501             result = keyframe.decode(*args, **decodeargs)
   5502             if func is not None:
   5503                 return func(result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in decode(exc, *args, **kwargs)
   5228         except KeyError as exc:
   5229             def decode(*args, exc=str(exc)[1:-1], **kwargs):
-> 5230                 raise ValueError(f'TiffPage {self.index}: {exc}')
   5231             return cache(decode)
   5232 
ValueError: TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.LZW: 5> requires the 'imagecodecs' package
```

When I I try to install *imagecodecs*, pip tells me that it is already installed:

```
bash-4.2$ pip install imagecodecs
Requirement already satisfied: imagecodecs in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2020.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from imagecodecs) (1.19.4)
bash-4.2$
```

But anyway, if I add *import imagecodecs* to the imports, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-920d3e93091b> in <module>
      8 from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
      9 import matplotlib
---> 10 import imagecodecs
     11 
     12 # https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/how-can-i-solve-this-error-from-tiff-file

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagecodecs'
```

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: You are mixing and failing to match your `pip` and `python` versions. Look at the error message from `pip install imagecodecs` and you'll see it is installed for Python 3.7 but the rest of your error messages indicate you are running Python 3.6

Comment: Thank you, I changed the whole environment to Pyhon 3.7 and I added `!pip install imagecodecs` before the imports. Now I don't get error anymore with the imports, but I get still the same error message stack with `ValueError: TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.LZW: 5> requires the 'imagecodecs' package`

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar error in google colab.
I tried the following before the "for" loop for reading the images:

```
pip install imagecodecs
```

It doesn't work at first and I got the same error. Then I restarted the code and the images were loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue on an hpc using VScode. Tifffile worked after re-starting the environment.